# sql server query to Linq to entites conversion doesn't retrieve records

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have table called "AttendanceTracker"... below is the snapshot of the table

[image]

and SQL query to retrieve records from this table is as follows

```
select EmployeeId, Dates, cast(datediff(hour, INTIME, OUTIME) as varchar)+':'+ 
   cast(datediff(minute, INTIME, OUTIME) 
   - datediff(hour, INTIME, OUTIME) * 60 as varchar)+':'+ 
   cast(datediff(second, INTIME, OUTIME) 
   - (datediff(minute, INTIME, OUTIME) * 60) as varchar) TotalTime

FROM (
SELECT INN.EmployeeId AS EmployeeId,Convert(DATE,INN.Time,101) AS Dates,MIN(INN.Time) AS INTIME, MAX(OUTT.Time) AS OUTIME

FROM [dbo].[AttendanceTrackers] AS INN,
     [dbo].[AttendanceTrackers] AS OUTT 
WHERE INN.Type = 'IN' AND 
      OUTT.Type = 'OUT' AND 
      INN.EmployeeId = 1 AND 
      OUTT.EmployeeId = INN.EmployeeId AND 
      Convert(DATE,INN.Time,101) = Convert(DATE,OUTT.Time,101)
GROUP BY INN.EmployeeId, INN.TenantID, CONVERT(DATE,INN.Time,101)
) X;
```

Query Output is as follows

[image]

LINQ to entities query is as follows

```
var query = from X in (
    (from INN in db.AttendanceTrackers
    from OUTT in db.AttendanceTrackers
    where
      INN.Type == "IN" &&
      OUTT.Type == "OUT" &&
      INN.EmployeeId == 1 &&
      OUTT.EmployeeId == INN.EmployeeId &&
      (DateTime)INN.Time == (DateTime)OUTT.Time
    group new {INN, OUTT} by new {
      INN.EmployeeId,
      INN.TenantId,
      Column1 = (DateTime?)(DateTime)INN.Time
    } into g
    select new {
      EmployeeId = g.Key.EmployeeId,
      Dates = g.Key.Column1,
      INTIME = (DateTime?)g.Min(p => p.INN.Time),
      OUTIME = (DateTime?)g.Max(p => p.OUTT.Time)
    }))
select new {
  X.EmployeeId,
  X.Dates,
  TotalTime = (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)SqlFunctions.DateDiff("hour",X.INTIME,X.OUTIME)) + ":" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)(SqlFunctions.DateDiff("minute",X.INTIME,X.OUTIME) - SqlFunctions.DateDiff("hour",X.INTIME,X.OUTIME) * 60)) + ":" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)(SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second",X.INTIME,X.OUTIME) - (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("minute",X.INTIME,X.OUTIME) * 60))))
}
```

The LINQ query doesnt return any records... can someone please help ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, so, so...

First, your first query (and the linq version) should use the join syntax, not the old "cartesian product with a where clause". This makes things much easier to understand.

Than, you can use

`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` to get the date part of a DateTime in linq to entities.

Then, I would enumerate before doing the `totalTime` display part, as it's much easier to do in linq2 objects than linq 2 entities. (Datetime2 - DateTime1), which gives you a Timestamp that you can easily format.

Which would do something like that (sorry for comment formatting, looks like it's not recognized as c#)

```
var query = 
    (from inn in db.AttendanceTrackers.Where(m => m.EmployeeId == 1 && m.Type == "IN")
     //of course, you could put the where clause on employeeId in another place
     join outt in db.AttendanceTrackers.Where(m => m.Type == "OUT") 
     //join on EmployeeId and Date part of the datetime
     on new {
          inn.EmployeeId,
          time = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(inn.Time)
      } equals new{
          outt.EmployeeId,
          time = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(outt.Time)
      }
      group new{inn,outt} 
      //group by EmployeeId, TenantId and Date part of the DateTime
      by new
      {
          inn.EmployeeId,
          inn.TenantId,
          day = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(Time)
      }
      into g
      //select first inTime and last outTime for the day + employeeId and day
      select new
      {
          employeeId = g.Key.EmployeeId,
          day = g.Key.day,
          inTime = g.Min(x => x.inn.Time),
          outTime = g.Max(x => x.outt.Time)
      })
      //enumerate, as we filtered all we needed
         .ToList()
         //easier way to format the desired values.
         .Select(x => new
         {
             x.employeeId,
             day = x.day,
             TotalTime = (x.outTime - x.inTime).ToString("hh:mm:ss")
         });
```

Comment: Gr8 Answer and superb explanation.... Following Line gives parsing error
   TotalTime = (x.outTime - x.inTime).ToString("hh:mm:ss")

Replacing with 
    TotalTime = (x.outTime - x.inTime).ToString()

will do....

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the SQL written it maybe be better to place the SQL in a stored procedure and map this in the entity framework. You can map this to a custom type as shown in your linq example. This way you only have one code base to maintain going forward whilst it provides the same functionality.

If you still want to use linq then you can use the solution suggested by Raphael and also use a Sql profiler against the server to determine the sql generated by the entity framework and where the bug may lie.